# Looking for a children's book about a boy who drifts to a mysterious island on an inflatable tube after being washed out to sea

Tags: story-identification, books, childrens-novel

The story based in Britain is, as far as I can remember, about a boy who falls asleep on an inflatable tube at sea - while on a family holiday to the beach.

He then drifts to a mysterious island whose inhabitants don't know about or come into contact with the outside world; and is adopted by the island's chief and his family.

The chief is the main fisherman as the island's hierarchy revolves around fishing.

---

@FuzzyBoots, (and @TheLethalCarrot) - I remember there being a fantasy element in terms of the island being in fog and inescapable. But those actual details were a bit "foggy" in my mind - so I left them out of the question.
I understand your concern and have posted on the Literature SE; apologies - newbie mistake.
Not sure on how to remove this question from this exchange.
And unable to post a comment due to permissions issue

However the chief's son cannot swim, which leads him to bully the boy as he see's the inflatable tube as the answer to his swimming problem.

The book is at least 40 years old.

Comment: This is a good question, but can you elaborate on the fantasy or science fiction aspects? If it doesn't have any, this may be a better match for the Literature SE.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I thought initially too but I think this may be borderline. _"mysterious island"_ with an untouched civilisation, drifting on an inflatable that far, etc. It very certainly _could_ be on topic but might not necessarily be so. Might be worth giving it the benefit of the doubt.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been cross posted to Lit (https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/18697/2987) where it is probably more appropriate anyway.

Comment: Also Thingy please follow the instructions here to [merge your accounts](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) as it looks like you've lost access to the first.